# Getting the last row from a ROW_NUMBER using SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am thinking there is a better way to grab the last row from a `row_number` instead of doing multiple nesting using T-SQL.

I need the total number of orders and the last ordered date. Say I have the following:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (PERSON_ID INT, ORDER_DATE DATE)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(1, '2016/01/01')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(1, '2016/01/02')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(1, '2016/01/03')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(2, '2016/01/01')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(2, '2016/01/02')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(3, '2016/01/01')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(3, '2016/01/02')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(3, '2016/01/03')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(3, '2016/01/04')
```

What I want is:

```
PERSON_ID   ORDER_DATE  ORDER_CNT
1           2016-01-03  3
2           2016-01-02  2
3           2016-01-04  4
```

Is there a better way to do this besides the following:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT *
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON_ID ORDER BY ORDER_CNT DESC) AS LAST_ROW
      FROM (
        SELECT *
             , ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON_ID ORDER BY ORDER_DATE) AS ORDER_CNT
          FROM @T
        ) AS A
    ) AS B
WHERE LAST_ROW = 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use this:

```
SELECT 
  PERSON_ID, 
  MAX(ORDER_DATE) AS ORDER_DATE, 
  COUNT(*) AS ORDER_CNT 
FROM @T
GROUP BY PERSON_ID
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  a.PERSON_ID
    ,   a.ORDER_DATE
    ,   a.ORDER_CNT
FROM
    (
    SELECT  PERSON_ID
        ,   ORDER_DATE
        ,   rn = ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON_ID ORDER BY ORDER_DATE DESC)
        ,   ORDER_CNT = COUNT(ORDER_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON_ID)
    FROM @T
    ) AS a
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY a.PERSON_ID;
```